# Fixing automatic scheme numbering

Tags: chemistry, auto-pst-pdf, chemnum, pstool

I want to use either the chemscheme or chemnum package to automatically label my compounds in my document. Both of these function via the .eps format which is a problem when using pdfLaTeX, the suggested fix for this is using the auto-pst-pdf package. In isolation this works for me, however it crashes when I also use biblatex and hyperref, I was hoping that pstool might offer a solution, however when I use this it doesn't change the markers within the document. Others have encountered the same problem but I'm not able to mimic or successfully replicate these solutions. I think this is simply because I'm very unfamiliar with how latex is build and what I can change in this. I am using VS code with Latex workshop (recipe: latexmk)

This is my 'preferred' package setup (pstool seems faster than auto-pst-pdf and chemscheme is a bit nicer than chemnum, but I am happy with any package combination that works). Is there anyone that can give me advice on how to get this working?

Edit: I messed around a lot in the meantime, it is still not working but I think installing perl and ghostscript helped somewhat (or it might be another thing I changed, I couldn't keep track). I editted the code to a MWE the file used can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sJJwSyI-XFpXwnqmueh-H_LUBaqlWUfO/view?usp=sharing):  In this example I have pstool active, now nothing happens in the figure (i.e. it prints TMP1, TMP2, TMP3. As an aside, I also tried to use psfrag directly this also did not do anything), if you % pstool and activate auto-pst-pdf it builds for a long time and then gives an empty page, and this error 'Float too large for page by 142.37236pt.' but I can't imagine that is the real problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
%\usepackage[journal=asbcd6]{achemso} %old bib style
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[runs=2, crop=off, cleanup=]{auto-pst-pdf} % Use EPS graphics with pdfLaTeX
%\usepackage{pstool}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}
%\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{chemscheme} %suports the \begin{scheme} environment and compound numbering
%\usepackage{natmove} %moves superscripted text past interpunction
%\setkeys{acs}{articletitle=true}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{margin=10pt, font=small,labelfont =bf}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,citestyle=chem-acs]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
testing hyperref \ref{scheme}.
\begin{scheme*}

    \schemeref[TMP1]{Boc-Ala}
    \schemeref[TMP2]{N-Benz}
    \schemeref[TMP3]{boc-couple}
    %\psfrag{TMP1}{Hey}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example}
    \caption{test}
    \label{scheme}
\end{scheme*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please prepare a complete and compilable MWE that allows others to reproduce your issue. What exactly does "it crashes" mean specifically? Do you get an error message? If so, which?

Comment: You mention others having had the same issue while you were not able to adapt their solutions. Please provide some relevant links to what you found.

Comment: Please be aware that the hyperref package should, with some few exceptions, be the last package in the preamble.